# treeview expand/collapse javascript

Tags: asp.net

in my asp.net treeview  if i click one parent node then it should be extended if i click again on that node it should be collapsed in treeview...
is any javascript availabe for this? or any code in selected node changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z5184w(VS.80).aspx) about enabling the expand/collapse on the client. See the **Enabling Client Script** section.

Basically you need to set `EnableClientScript` to true for the control.

```
TreeView1.EnableClientScript = true;
```

Or

```
<asp:treeview id="..." runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" ... />
```

Comment: is it enough for extend and collapse for same parent by clicking on that...or any javascript?

Comment: when i click on that parent node it could expanded but if i again click on that parent it didnt collapse why?

Comment: have you looked to see if there is a javascript error occuring? Is there some javascript you've written that could be interfering?

Comment: can u provide any javascript for this?

Comment: `EnableClientScript` will add the javascript you need. If that's not working you need to investigate why it's not working. Is your browser reporting an error?